Implementation of Common Event Trigger functionality for various checkboxes in WPF
I have various checkboxes with Interaction.Triggers and Event Triggers for both Check and Uncheck for each checkbox as shown below. When the checkbox is checked or unchecked I will be catching the CommandParameter value which is different for each checkbox in my ViewModel. I am required to make the Event Triggers as a common code in my XAML which has to work for every different checkbox by catching the CommandParameter value.
<framectl:BoundCheckBox UIElementTag="V_NVMCPhaseTripBlockProfileDependent" LabelType="Empty" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="17" TabIndex="17" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProfileDependentChecked_Command}" CommandParameter="V_NVMCPhaseTripBlockProfileDependent"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProfileDependentUnChecked_Command}" CommandParameter="V_NVMCPhaseTripBlockProfileDependent"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</framectl:BoundCheckBox>

<framectl:BoundCheckBox UIElementTag="V_NVMCGroundTripBlockProfileDependent" LabelType="Empty" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="17" TabIndex="26" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProfileDependentChecked_Command}" CommandParameter="V_NVMCGroundTripBlockProfileDependent"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProfileDependentUnChecked_Command}" CommandParameter="V_NVMCGroundTripBlockProfileDependent"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</framectl:BoundCheckBox>

I have tried the below common code by using a style resource, but that is not firing the command method.
<framectl:CCSUserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ProfileDependentCheckedStyle" TargetType="framectl:BoundCheckBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Checked">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProfileDependentChecked_Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Unchecked">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProfileDependentUnChecked_Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</framectl:CCSUserControl.Resources>

<framectl:BoundCheckBox Style="{StaticResource ProfileDependentCheckedStyle}" UIElementTag="V_NVMCPhaseTripBlockProfileDependent" LabelType="Empty" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="17" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TabIndex="8" CommandParameter="V_NVMCPhaseTripBlockProfileDependent"/>

<framectl:BoundCheckBox Style="{StaticResource ProfileDependentCheckedStyle}" UIElementTag="V_NVMCGroundTripBlockProfileDependent" LabelType="Empty"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="17"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TabIndex="8" CommandParameter="V_NVMCGroundTripBlockProfileDependent"/>

